# Faster way to subset xts

Tags: r, xts

I have a large `xts` that I want to filter by month and by date for every year present.

```
library(xts)   
junk <- xts(sample.int(101, size = 1461, replace = T), seq(as.Date('2006-01-01'), as.Date('2009-12-31'), 'days'))
junk_sma10 = TTR::SMA(x = junk, n = 10) ## trailing 10 day avg
```

Right now I'md doing it via a loop for every day and month value which takes a while. I know R is better at doing things vectors at a time.

```
months_filtered <- idx_apcp30[.indexmon(junk_sma10) == 1]     ## filter for feb
final_filtered <- months_filtered[.indexmday(months_filtered) == 15] ## filter for 16th
```

The output is a unique xts for every day of the year.

```
           SMA
2006-02-16 61.0
2007-02-16 50.5
2008-02-16 60.5
2009-02-16 54.1
```

and then the next iteration (+1 mday) would produce

```
            SMA
2006-02-17 64.3
2007-02-17 48.4
2008-02-17 66.1
2009-02-17 48.6
```

I need to produce and store every xts that this process produces. How do I do this not in a loop?

I found a solution like this:

```
junk[seq(as.Date('2006-01-01'),as.Date('2009-12-31'),by='year')]
```

But I would still have to iterate over every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to `split` your xts object into chunks by month and day.

```
# if using xts < 0.10-0 (bug work-around)
month_day <- split(junk_sma10, as.numeric(format(index(junk_sma10), "%m%d")))

# requires xts >= 0.10-0
month_day <- split(junk_sma10, format(index(junk_sma10), "%m%d"))
```

Now `month_day` is a list, where every element is the same month and day of the month for each year.  Then you can continue your analysis by using `lapply` to call a function on each list element.